# pip install accepts --> fails

Tags: python, pip, installation

I'm trying to pip install accepts, but the code fails. Before the red text of the error (which just says the path of the error pretty much), there is:
"TypeError: 'package' must be a string (dot-separated), list, or tuple"

I have already pip installed this on a different computer but for some reason this error pops up in my home computer. Does anyone know how to solve this?
Note: I have pip installed other modules on my computer, this specific module returns the error.

Image for cmd error: [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4UP1.png)

Edit: I've been trying at this for a while, even went to the creator's github (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/accepts/0.0.2). At this point I tried manually downloading the library which also didn't yield a result. It'd be really helpful if someone could pinpoint me in a direction. Thanks.

Comment: please post the error in its entirety.

Comment: just added a screenshot of the cmd error

Comment: What is the exact command that you're running to get this error?

Comment: exact command:

pip install accepts