# Can't Move Library From one Computer to Another

Tags: python, pip

I have on my domputer downloaded a library (via pip install) a while ago, and I can't seem to be able to download the same exact library on a different PC. Does anyone know how I can manually copy the library from one computer and transfer it to the other? My IDE is PyCharm and pip install is returning an error which prevents me from downloading the package on my second computer.

Comment: what error is returning after `pip`

Comment: I've asked that question to no results quite a while ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49201498/pip-install-accepts-fails
I've given up on that approach after many failed attempts and am trying to focus on moving the library that I have already manually.